# extract a list of all Azure Active Directory users through Powershell within Azure Function App save as csv and then send to ftp site

Tags: azure, function, powershell, ftp, azure-functions

im trying to use azure function app to extract a list of all Azure Active Directory users through Powershell and save as a csv and then upload to a ftp server

there is a lot of old articles but azure seemed to build out more functions...

my first challenge is getting the powershell commands to read our aad environment

any information, articles or pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Install the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module. To get info on AAD users you can use mainly `Get-AzureADUser`.

Comment: ive found the following
 https://support.gridprosoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016207614-Setting-Up-a-Function-to-Access-Azure-AD-data 
i believe this would be a start to adding azure AD i have the Get-AzureADuser ps script it runs locally but not through azure functions

Answer (score 0):

Use the below powershell script :

```
>Get-AzureAdUser
```

This will list use users in Ad

To Export the list in csv use the below query :

```
>Get-AzureADUser | export-csv file.csv
```

[image]

Comment: you can follow this article to run this query in azure function  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-powershell-function-app/

Comment: unfortunately that is showing the old experience, ultimately i need to run on a timer every night it will pull data from aad export to csv and then upload to a ftp site